# how to fix tensorflow throwing dll loading error. python 3.7. windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, dll, python-3.7

I wanted to get started using tensorflow.
i downloaded tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl and installed it via pip which worked.

but when i want to run the tensorflow tutorialcode it throws the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
>    line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site- 
>    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>    
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site- 
>    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in 
>    swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, 
>    description)
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", > line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", > line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/johnson/PycharmProjects/Data 
>    exploration/MNISTTensorflow.py", line 4, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>    
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
>    disable=unused-import
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, 
>    in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>    File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
>    line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
>    line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site- 
>    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>    
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\PycharmProjects\Data exploration\Data 
>    exploration\venv\lib\site- 
>    packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in 
>    swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, 
>    description)
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", 
>    line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\Users\johnson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", 
>    line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>    ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>    above this error message when asking for help.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

i tried downloading and installing the 1.12.0 version. but when i want to add the package to the interpreter (via "settings" in pycharm), only the 1.13.1 version showed up (which was already uninstalled). that just adds to my confusion. as you surely can see, im new to python. i hope my questions are not too stupid. thank you!

i use: 
- windos 7 (64bit)
- Python 3.7
- PyCharm community edition 2018.3.2
- GeForce GT 425m
- i5 CPU M580